# Download manager that uses slaves to bypass "single connection per IP" restriction?

Tags: connection, ip, download-manager, bypass

Of course I know that if the admin of a server restricts his ftp server to have only one connection per IP that he might have good reasons for it.

As you all know things sometimes may become complicated, I wondered if there are download manager that you install on a bunch of computers each having different a IP? Like master slave principle and using the master on your desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm a little googling gave me this: http://linuxandfriends.com/2008/11/01/curl-split-a-file-and-download-simultaneously-from-multiple-locations/

Using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and the range option and some bash scripting may solve this.